# Exclude provided jackson version from JBoss 7 EAP

Tags: jboss, war, jboss-eap-7

I am trying to use a newer version of Jackson as JBoss 7 EAP delivers. To solve my issue I have created a *jboss-deployment-structure.xml* file which is contained in my war deployment.

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <!--<module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core" slot="main" />-->
            <!--<module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-annotations" slot="main" />-->
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind" slot="main" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

But it seems that JBoss uses the delivered module instead of the provided dependency.

> ModuleClassLoader for Module
>   "com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind:main" from local module
>   loader @134593bf (finder: local module finder @4bb4de6a (roots:
>   ...\jboss-eap-7.0\modules,...\jboss-eap-7.0\modules\system\layers\base))

I have found a similar question [JBoss 7 Classloader -- Exclude Module Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25515171/390177) but it didn't help me.

What did I miss?

Comment: is your deployment an EAR?

Comment: You'll want to be careful doing this as other Jackson modules depend on that module. Is there a reason you need a newer version?

Comment: We need it for Apache Camel.

Answer (score 19):

I ran into the exact same problem with Jackson, and I got it to work in my EAP 7 using this `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` :

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-annotations" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.jackson-jaxrs-json-provider" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson-provider" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

It appears like as long as any *other* modules list jackson as their dependency in their respective `module.xml`, it just simply doesn't get excluded, and EAP can't be arsed to even throw a warning about it.

**Edit 2018-02-19:** When upgrading from EAP 7.0.0 to 7.1.0, things broke again, owing to updated Jackson jars.

This is the crucial part of the stacktrace:

```
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: WFLYEJB0442: Unexpected Error
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:185)
[...]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:161) [wildfly-ee-7.1.0.GA-redhat-11.jar:7.1.0.GA-redhat-11]
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    [...]()Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper; @89: invokevirtual
  Reason:
    Type 'com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jdk8/Jdk8Module' (current frame, stack[1]) is not assignable to 'com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/Module'
```

So we exclude those as well:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-annotations" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jackson-datatype-jdk8" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jackson-datatype-jsr310" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.jackson-jaxrs-json-provider" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson-provider" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: I did the same as suggested, but still I got error as `Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoadError: com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jackson-datatype-jdk8` , I am using wildfly 14 and working with keycloak create an issue. Java 11 and spring 4.3.12.

Comment: It resolves my problem, I was excluding from deployment , instead from sub-deployment. Thanks.

Comment: hmmm still getting the `is not assignable to` errors mentioned above. I do include `jackson-datatype-jdk8` and `jackson-datatype-jsr310` explicitly in my gradle build script. Not sure if that makes this different.

Comment: yeah in my case i was deploying spring boot with spring jdbc and jpa enabled. this fixes my issues.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like the jax-rs submodule from jboss eap 7 uses jackson. As soon as you skip this submodule, you will get rid of the jboss jackson version:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="jaxrs"/>
        </exclude-subsystems>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

(only makes sense if you don't use jaxrs ;-)

Comment: Well, we do. Just that we explicitly use Jackson as well. :-/

Comment: I have a problem with the deserialization of Json, “prevented for security reasons” And J am trying to exclude the library responsible for that exception, Jackson-mapper-asl, is that also part of jaxrs?

Comment: I was facing issues after upgrading jboss from 6.2 to 7.3:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68781412/different-response-when-application-deployed-in-jboss-6-2-vs-jboss-7-3

This answer has solved my issue. Thanks much.